# What does the word "trinkets" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a game, which is a modified version of Pokémon:

> You can train it up and add **trinkets** and attractive features to your pool before sending it out to compete.

I know the lexical meanings of the word "trinkets", but am not sure if it means "ornaments" or "objects". Unfortunately, there is nothing in the text which could give me clues for the meaning of the said word.

Answer (score 1):

Trinkets are a sort of knick-knacks, usually small decorative objects of low value. I don't see the context as changing that, except inasmuch as it might be a more specific meaning in the context of the game.